# String comparing before_save in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When comparing two string expressions `"batman" != "batman"` cant create an object,
but when `"batman" != "robin"` it successfully created object, what is happening?

```
class WebsiteLink < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :external

  before_save :external?


  private
  def external?
    if "batman" != "batman"
        self.external = true
    else
        self.external = false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a `before_filter` returns `false` the filter chain stops. Since Ruby returns the return value of the last expression (`self.external =` in your example) `save` will not happen if  you assign `false` to `self.external`.

btw: `self.external = "batman" != "batman"` is much shorter and does the same than:

```
if "batman" != "batman"
  self.external = true
else
  self.external = false
end
```

So if you want your example to work even if `external` is assigned to false, you need to return `true` explicit:

```
class WebsiteLink < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :external

  before_save :determine_external

private
  def determine_external
    self.external = "batman" != "batman"
    true
  end
end
```